# Hibernate annotation for Index with Btree structure

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to tell Hibernate/JPA to make an Index but with a structure like BTree when creating the DDL from the annotations of the Entities?

The @Index annotation does not have such an option.If you have to amend the DDL generated by Hibernate in order to tell it to use a certain structure, it beats the autogeneration purpose.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. For that reason, i.e. that the JPA annotations cannot handle all the details of schema creation, I prefer to use tools like Liquibase, Flyway, etc.

Comment: please add your comment as an answer so I accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At of this time, JPA does not provide a way to specify this. I do not know if there is a *Hibernate-specific* way - although I could not find anything with a quick search.

For this and other reasons, I prefer to use a database tool like Liquibase, Flyway etc to manage the DB schema for anything other than trivial schemas.